# How to convert ReactDOM.findDOMNode from class component to a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, addeventlistener, react-functional-component

I found on the internet this code:

```
  class ResizablePanels extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      isDragging: false,
      panels: [300, 300]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener("mousemove", this.resizePanel);
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener("mouseup", this.stopResize);
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener("mouseleave", this.stopResize);
  } ....
```

Full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-ritchie-83rsy?file=/src/index.js

And I´d like to know, how this code snippet above transform to function component, especially how to transform section with componentDidMount(). I know, that I need to use hook "useEffect", but is it possible to use addEventListener for example with "useRef"? I don´t want to use ReactDOM.findDOMNode.

Thank you.

Comment: Frankly? You don't. What you've quoted looks like [poor practice](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode) (in a couple of ways -- it fails to pass on props to `super`). Use React's event handling, or at worst a `ref` on the top-level element of the component. Other than that part, it's just a [state hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Comment: Yes it is possible to transfer it to a function component, what have you tried?

Comment: I tried with useRef, but it didn´t work and to be hones, useRef isn´t the best solution I think.

Answer (score -1):

Frankly? You don't. What you've quoted doesn't look very good, for at least a couple of reasons:

- `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` is generally [poor practice](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode). Using it just to hook up event handlers is very much poor practice; use React's events instead, or at worst, a `ref` on the top-level element.
- It doesn't pass `props` to `super()`.

Instead:

```
function ResizablePanels() {
    const [isDragging, setIsDragging = useState(false);
    const [panels, setPanels] = useState([300, 300]); // *** Only if they change during component lifecycle

    const resizePanel = (evt) => {
        // ...
    };
    const stopPanel = (evt) => {
        // ...
    };

    return (
        <div onMouseMove={resizePanel} onMouseUp={stopResize} onMouseLeave={stopResize}>
        ...
        </div>
    );
}
```

...or whatever top-level element there is (doesn't have to ba `div`).

Comment: Yeah, I tried that same solution, but ahead in the full code, there is a problem, that it uses event.clientX. So there´s need to useEffect hook to be able use startResize function. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @MichaelRýdl - People can only help you with what's in the question. (Links to other sites can disappear, etc.; if you want to get help with code, that code must be **in** the question). I have no idea whether you need `useEffect` somewhere, but I wouldn't expect you to just for resize events.